# Position a Minipage for subfigure with side captions

Tags: minipage, subcaption, sidecap, subfig

I'm using the `minipage` environment in order to put a caption for a `subfigure` on the side.
It works fine. But I'm have a problem because I want the figure to be exactly in the horizontal middle of my page and the `caption` (`minipage`) to start after it.

CODE:

```
\documentclass[
    BCOR12mm,
    DIV18,
    headsepline,
    twoside,
    idxtotoc,
    bibtotoc,
    liststotoc,
    openany,
    pointlessnumbers,
    12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[hang]{caption}        
    \usepackage{subcaption}              
    \usepackage[final]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight]{smallfig}
            \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \caption{small}
            \end{minipage}
            \label{label}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[m]{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight]{bigfig1}
            \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \caption{big1}
            \end{minipage}
            \label{label}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight]{bigfig3}
            \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \caption{big2}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{3 centered Subfigures under each other with side captions on the right}
        \label{help}
      \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\centering` here causes the whole `subfigure` (figure + caption) to be in the center which makes the figure slightly aligned to the left. I would like it to be exactly centered.

Edit: To clarify my question a little bit more here is a hand drown image for what I need:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    BCOR12mm,
    DIV18,
    headsepline,
    twoside,
    idxtotoc,
    bibtotoc,
    liststotoc,
    openany,
    pointlessnumbers,
    12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[hang,singlelinecheck=false]{caption} % <------
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.1\textheight, valign=m]{smallfig}%
            \makebox[0pt][l]{\quad % <------
            \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \caption{small}
            \end{minipage}
                            }
            \label{label}
        \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.4\textheight, valign=m]{bigfig1}%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\quad % <------
           \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
            \caption{big1}
            \end{minipage}
                        }
            \label{label}
        \end{subfigure}

        \medskip
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.4\textheight, valign=m]{bigfig3}%
   \makebox[0pt][l]{\quad  % <------
        \begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
        \caption{big2 big2 big2 big2 big2 big2 big2}
        \end{minipage}
                    }
        \caption{3 centered Subfigures under each other with side captions on the right}
        \label{help}
      \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**edit (1):** 
for vertical centering of captions you need to move image baseline to its vertical middle. this can be achieved on different ways ... one of them is use `adjustbox` package (as added in *mwe* above):

**edit (2):**

- for space between sub images is added `\medskip` between them (if it is desired bigger (or smaller) vertical distances between images, then it should be replaced with `\bigskip`  or `\smallskip` or `\vspace{}, etc)
- for better positioning of sub captions is added `singlelinecheck=false` to options of the package `caption`
- also the `minimapge`s with captions are moved to right with insertion of `\quad` before them
- `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` (where  `0pt` is width of box and `l` position of box, for details see [LaTeX/Boxes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes)) make centering of images independent from captions' widths.

Comment: Thank you very much. There are still two little things though:
1- What if I want to put the `minipage` aligned to the horizontal center line of the `subfigure` (or to the top for that matter) instead of the bottom?
2- What does the "l" in `\makebox[0pt][l]` do?

Comment: for `makebox` see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes, for centering your caption see edit of my answer.

Comment: Forget the question about makebox, it was silly.
Your solution by polling the image baseline further towards the middle of the page doesn't work for me. I have three images and I'm putting captions to the side in order to keep them all on one page AND not make them "touch". SO I really would like to only move the caption itself without having to move the figure..

Comment: then please clarify your question. the best way with some hand drawn image. now image are centered (i didn't draw all three, the principle for third is the same) and caption are right of them, also vertical centered to image. so far this was your demand ...

Comment: Sorry about not being clear enough, just too stressed because of thesis writing and so. Anyway now there is an image in the question